# Problems with Rollapplyr function due to NA values (that should not be removed) in R

Tags: r, rollapply

I have a dataframe:

```
      date comp  ei
1   1/1/73    A  NA
2   1/4/73    A 0.6
3   1/7/73    A 0.7
4  1/10/73    A 0.9
5   1/1/74    A 0.4
6   1/4/74    A 0.5
7   1/7/74    A 0.7
8  1/10/74    A 0.7
9   1/1/75    A 0.4
10  1/4/75    A 0.5
11  1/1/73    B 0.8
12  1/4/73    B 0.8
13  1/7/73    B 0.5
14 1/10/73    B 0.6
15  1/1/74    B 0.3
16  1/4/74    B 0.2
17  1/1/73    C  NA
18  1/4/73    C 0.6
19  1/7/73    C 0.4
20 1/10/73    C 0.8
21  1/1/74    C 0.7
22  1/4/74    C 0.9
23  1/7/74    C 0.4
24 1/10/74    C 0.3
```

I want to calculate the rolling std. deviation of ei grouped by comp. I want the rolling standard deviation of the last 8 lines - but if only 6 lines exists, so far, it should still take the rolling std. deviation of those. So I use width = 8 and partial = 6 in this code:

```
roll <- function(z) rollapplyr(z, width = 8, FUN = sd, fill = NA, partial = 6)  
df <- transform(df, roll = ave(ei, comp, FUN = roll))
```

However, due to the fact that some of my 'ei' values are 'NA' the partial part of the function doesn't work, since there is an NA in one of the past 8 lines. So of course after 6 lines the std. dev. is NA. Only for comp = B, the partial = 6 works. The results are seen below:

```
      date comp  ei      roll
1   1/1/73    A  NA        NA
2   1/4/73    A 0.6        NA
3   1/7/73    A 0.7        NA
4  1/10/73    A 0.9        NA
5   1/1/74    A 0.4        NA
6   1/4/74    A 0.5        NA
7   1/7/74    A 0.7        NA
8  1/10/74    A 0.7        NA
9   1/1/75    A 0.4 0.1726888
10  1/4/75    A 0.5 0.1772811
11  1/1/73    B 0.8        NA
12  1/4/73    B 0.8        NA
13  1/7/73    B 0.5        NA
14 1/10/73    B 0.6        NA
15  1/1/74    B 0.3        NA
16  1/4/74    B 0.2 0.2503331
17  1/1/73    C  NA        NA
18  1/4/73    C 0.6        NA
19  1/7/73    C 0.4        NA
20 1/10/73    C 0.8        NA
21  1/1/74    C 0.7        NA
22  1/4/74    C 0.9        NA
23  1/7/74    C 0.4        NA
24 1/10/74    C 0.3        NA
```

I would have rather wanted my results to look as it does below, where the first std. dev is calculated for comp A in line number 7 for the previous 6 values (not NA) and where comp C has a std. dev in line 23 and 24:

```
      date comp  ei      roll
1   1/1/73    A  NA        NA
2   1/4/73    A 0.6        NA
3   1/7/73    A 0.7        NA
4  1/10/73    A 0.9        NA
5   1/1/74    A 0.4        NA
6   1/4/74    A 0.5        NA
7   1/7/74    A 0.7 0.1751190
8  1/10/74    A 0.7 0.1618347
9   1/1/75    A 0.4 0.1726888
10  1/4/75    A 0.5 0.1772811
11  1/1/73    B 0.8        NA
12  1/4/73    B 0.8        NA
13  1/7/73    B 0.5        NA
14 1/10/73    B 0.6        NA
15  1/1/74    B 0.3        NA
16  1/4/74    B 0.2 0.2503331
17  1/1/73    C  NA        NA
18  1/4/73    C 0.6        NA
19  1/7/73    C 0.4        NA
20 1/10/73    C 0.8        NA
21  1/1/74    C 0.7        NA
22  1/4/74    C 0.9        NA
23  1/7/74    C 0.4 0.2065591
24 1/10/74    C 0.3 0.2267787
```

How can I do this without running a na.omit code before calculating the rolling std. dev? The reason why I don't want to remove NA's is that I need the lines with comp and dates (plus other columns in my real dataset). Also, removing my NA values might, in my real dataset, lead to removing NA's in the middle of a period so that the rolling std. dev. function won't fit with the dates and my results will be wrong.

Is there a way to deal with this without removing the NA values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** FUN computes sd if there are at least 6 non-NAs and otherwise returns NA.
Then proceed as in the question.

```
library(zoo)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%y")
FUN <- function(x) if (length(na.omit(x)) >= 6) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE) else NA
roll <- function(z) rollapplyr(z, width = 8, FUN = FUN, 
      fill = NA, partial = 6)  
transform(df, roll = ave(ei, comp, FUN = roll))
```

**2)** The other possibility is to use na.omit and then merge the result back with the original data frame.

```
library(zoo)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%y")
roll <- function(z) rollapplyr(z, width = 8, FUN = sd, fill = NA, partial = 6)  

df_roll_0 <- transform(na.omit(df), roll = ave(ei, comp, FUN = roll)) 
df_roll_m <- merge(df, df_roll_0, all = TRUE)
o <- with(df_roll_m, order(comp, date))
df_roll <- df_roll_m[o, ]
```

**2a)** This could also be expressed using dplyr/tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%y")
roll <- function(z) rollapplyr(z, width = 8, FUN = sd, fill = NA, partial = 6)  

df_roll_0 <- df %>%
  drop_na %>%
  group_by(comp) %>%
  mutate(roll = roll(ei)) %>%
  ungroup

df %>%
  left_join(df_roll_0)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "      date comp  ei
1   1/1/73    A  NA
2   1/4/73    A 0.6
3   1/7/73    A 0.7
4  1/10/73    A 0.9
5   1/1/74    A 0.4
6   1/4/74    A 0.5
7   1/7/74    A 0.7
8  1/10/74    A 0.7
9   1/1/75    A 0.4
10  1/4/75    A 0.5
11  1/1/73    B 0.8
12  1/4/73    B 0.8
13  1/7/73    B 0.5
14 1/10/73    B 0.6
15  1/1/74    B 0.3
16  1/4/74    B 0.2
17  1/1/73    C  NA
18  1/4/73    C 0.6
19  1/7/73    C 0.4
20 1/10/73    C 0.8
21  1/1/74    C 0.7
22  1/4/74    C 0.9
23  1/7/74    C 0.4
24 1/10/74    C 0.3"
df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: This doesn't work either because it includes the NA in the partial part as well. This means that the first rolling std. dev. is already calculated in line number 6. But here I only have 5 actual values of ei - but I want 6. So the first std. dev should be calculated in line number 7.

Comment: I already pointed that out. in the answer. At any rate I have added a second approach.

Comment: Thanks! This works for my example. 

Do you have any suggestions on what to do if I have NA values in the middle of a period? Let's say I have a NA value for comp A in row 3. If this is removed by df_roll_0 <- transform(na.omit(df), roll = ave(ei, comp, FUN = roll)) for example, my standard deviation would skip this quarter and instead use another quarter in the roll function. By this I wouldn't get the last 8 quarters, but the last 9 skipping quarter 2

Comment: Use (1) except change the FUN= in rollapplyr to return NA if there are fewer than 6 non-NA's passed.